# What is the difference between AVCaptureDevice’s hasFlash and hasTorch properties?

Tags: ios, avcapturedevice

`AVCaptureDevice` has both `hasFlash` and `hasTorch` properties (and similar other methods/properties). What is the difference between the flash and the torch?

Also, do any iOS devices exist with only one of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iPhone devices both cameras have flash: back camera has a LED camera flash and can operate in a torch mode and front camera uses display as a flash (displaying for the short period of time white screen emits enough light) but display cannot be used as a torch.

Checking [device hasFlash] to set LED flash ON/OFF programmatically from the list of AVCaptureDevice:

**NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];**

is not enough, since both cameras will pass condition [device hasFlash], but setting [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn] for the front camera may cause app crash. The best is probably to check both:

```
if ([device hasFlash] && [device hasTorch]) {
 [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
 [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]; // for example
 [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A torch is the light that stays on. Think flashlight if you are using American English.

A flash is the brief bright light used when taking a photograph.

All newer phones have both. I believe the last iPod touch has both. It's most likely only older devices that had a flash and no torch.

Comment: So does this mean that I can’t have the flash on indefinitely? Also, should I use the flash or the torch to provide illumination when recording on the camera?

Comment: Use the torch for a long lasting light.